# variable in ng-repeat won't bind to model in ng-file-upload

Tags: angularjs, ng-file-upload

In this case blob files won't bind to the image variables

```
<div ng-repeat="image in images track by $index">
   <div ngf-drop ng-model="image"></div>
</div>
```

But in this case it works:

```
<div ng-repeat="image in images track by $index">
   <div ngf-drop ng-model="images[$index]"></div>
</div>
```

Yet `{{image == images[$index}}` returns true if I put in the ng-repeat loop...

How come the image variable in the first example won't bind ?

Comment: So image === images[$index] is true?

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to explain this with my limited experience, correct me if I'm wrong :).

According to [doc of ngRepeat](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/docs/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat):

> Each template instance gets its own scope, where the given loop variable is set to the current collection item...

Which means every `<div>` generated by your `ng-repeat` has its own scope, and an `image` attribute has been bind to each of them. But `images` was bind to the **parent scope** of `ng-repeat`.

Back to our question, when you do `ng-model="image"`, actually you have bind it to a scope's of a template but not the one(`images`) in your controller, that's why the change won't bind to `images`.